# Get an WARC achive file with all files from a given domain, using from commoncrawl.org

Tags: common-crawl

[Commoncrawl datasets](http://commoncrawl.org/2016/07/june-2016-crawl-archive-now-available/) are splitted by segments.
**How to extract a subset of the common-crawl data-set? I need a WARC archive file (or several archive files) with all the files from a given domain, such as example.com?**

Note: [common_crawl_index](https://github.com/trivio/common_crawl_index) allows to do that by running `bin/remote_copy copy "com.ipc.www" --bucket commoncrawl_sample --key common_crawl/ipc_crawl`, but the project is outdated: it only works for 2012 datasets, and it does not accept WARC, WAT or WET files.

Note: Also, http://index.commoncrawl.org/ allows to find the segments for a given url prefix, but there is not a utility to download only that pages, such as the previous `remote_copy` command.

PS: I am aware I can implement a program to do so. Here I am asking if common-crawl (or someone else) already thought and implemented this feature.

Comment: I've tried with index.commoncrawl.org, but I didn't manage to make it work: https://github.com/ikreymer/cdx-index-client/issues/3